# Indesign: Javascript to access the New Hyperlink panel

Tags: adobe-indesign, batch-processing, javascript, formatting

I want to create what is hopefully a simple javascript action that I can assign to a keyboard shortcut to save me clicking the same steps over and over.

Basically, I want to highlight my text, then have a script run that will open the dialog box for "New Hyperlink Destination"

I'm not sure about the InDesign DOM so if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: DOM is used for webpages. So technically your looking for API

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need a script for this.

InDesign has something called `Quick Apply`, which is a list of every feature and you can use this to call menu functions from the keyboard, without moving your mouse. To do this:

- Highlight some text.
- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Start typing "New Hyp...." — as you type, InDesign will already auto-select the "New Hyperlink destination" for you — and you only need to do this once, because InDesign will remember your last action, so every time you open this, the "New Hyperlink destination" will be pre-selected.
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to access the "New Hyperlink destination" panel and type in your website address.
- Repeat as many times as needed.

Also documented here: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/user-guide.html/indesign/using/formatting-text.ug.html

[image]